# Is it possible to check if there is a document in a collection?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way where i can check if there is at least 1 or more document in a collection in python?

I've tried this, it works if there is a document but if it does not have any document the loop doesn't run at all which makes sense cause there isn't any document to be loop through.

```
currentGame = db.collection(u'currentGame').stream()
try:
    for doc in currentGame:
        if doc.exists:
            print("exists")
        else:
            print("no document")

except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print("not found")
```